# jdbcTemplateObject.batchUpdate() throws a TransientDataAccessResourceException Parameter index out of range (4 > 3)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-jdbc

Using `Java 1.8` and `Spring Framework 4.0.3-RELEASE`, I am trying to insert one row into a MySQL database, after obtaining values from external feed.

Trying this:

```
private static JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject = null;
private static final String INSERT_QUERY = "insert into order_table(id,order_id,created_time,updated_time)VALUES(?,?,now(),now())";

parseFeedAndStoreIntoDB() {
    List<Object[]> insertData = new ArrayList<>();
    SqlRowSet sqlRowSet = null;

    // id, order_id, created_time, updated_time have values 
    insertData.add(new Object[] {id, order_id, created_time, updated_time});
    if (insertData.size() > 0) {
        // It breaks here
        jdbcTemplateObject.batchUpdate(INSERT_QUERY, insertData);
    }
}
```

When I run this method, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in parseFeedAndStoreIntoDB() method
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL 
[insert into order_table(id,order_id,created_time,updated_time)VALUES(?,?,now(), now());]; Parameter index out of range (4 > 3).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: 
Parameter index out of range (4 > 3).
```

Have counted the rows and they are 4 in my Java code and also in the MySQL database table that I created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query has bind parameters for `id` and `order_id`, the other two fields are set to `now()` in the query. Change

```
insertData.add(new Object[] {id, order_id, created_time, updated_time});
```

to

```
insertData.add(new Object[] {id, order_id});
```

**or** change

```
private static final String INSERT_QUERY = "insert into "
        + "order_table(id,order_id,created_time,updated_time) "
        + "VALUES(?,?,now(),now())";
```

to

```
private static final String INSERT_QUERY = "insert into "
        + "order_table(id,order_id,created_time,updated_time) "
        + "VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: Thank you the second suggestion worked!